# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '_DT_CellIndex' of undefined

I searched the web and found that it usually occurs when the count of th mismatches the count of td.

But I don't think that is causing the problem.
See the table defination below :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chat').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
    });
});
```

```xml
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="chat">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>From</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Message</th>
      <th>Time of Messgae</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="jhon_1523607791051" from="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>Hey Rylie</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 08:23:11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="rylie_1523607808352" from="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>Hey Jhon</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 08:23:29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>rajanjadav</td>
      <td><i class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i> PTT Message</td>
      <td>13-04-18 08:36:21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="rylie_1523608843382" from="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>what are you doing</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 08:40:43</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="jhon_1523608972383" from="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>Nothing much</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 08:42:52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="jhon_1523609330813" from="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>This is for jqyeur</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 08:48:50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="rylie_1523609341479" from="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>okay got it msg</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 08:49:01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="jhon_1523611389535" from="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>Say else what are you doing</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 09:23:09</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="rylie_1523611415081" from="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>nothing much just coding right now</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 09:23:35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="chat" id="jhon_1523611468570" from="jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC">
          <body>What's ur password</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 09:24:28</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td><i class="material-icons">play_circle_filled</i> PTT Message</td>
      <td>13-04-18 09:27:18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>jhon</td>
      <td>rajanjadav</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="groupchat" id="jhon_1523611651354" from="rajanjadav__umobilityptt.7600556046@conference.ptt.fms.bizrtc/jhon__umobilityptt.7600556046">
          <body>This message is sent in bizrtc group</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 09:27:31</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>rylie</td>
      <td>rajanjadav</td>
      <td>
        <message xmlns:cli="jabber:client" to="rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046@ptt.fms.bizrtc/bizRTC" cli:subject="TEXT MESSAGE" cli:lang="en" type="groupchat" id="rylie_1523613602613" from="rajanjadav__umobilityptt.7600556046@conference.ptt.fms.bizrtc/rylie__umobilityptt.7600556046">
          <body>what happened in the meeting with Alliance</body>
          <request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"></request>
        </message>
      </td>
      <td>13-04-18 10:00:03</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What can be the possible solution for this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DataTables expects the table to be populated consistently with each row, with the same number of columns. The cause is the empty  elements in your HTML.

```
<tr>
</tr>
```

If you remove those empty rows, the error will go.

Comment: Even if I craft my own empty message row with a <tr> with column spanning across all columns causes this error, not just completely empty <tr>s!

Comment: Yep, that would also happen - DataTables doesn't support `colspan` within the table's body, only in the `thead` header.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI: datatables also do not play well with colspan. I have a table with 3 cells, but one colspan=3 row and they give the same error.